# Different searching results in local Nominatim and openstreetmap.org

Tags: openstreetmap, geocoding, nominatim

I've just installed Nominatim using [this guide](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Installation). I've successfully import fresh osm.bz2 file with data for Saint-Petersburg, Russia into my postgresql database.

Nominatim search script works, but it shows another results, than openstreetmap.org and unfortunately can't find addresses with house numbers. For example, I try to find "60, Невский проспект". Openstreetmap.org works fine and finds a needful house, but local Nominatim finds only street with the same address, without house number.

So, what is the matter of such behaviour and how to aim the same search results as openstreetmap.org? Any ideas?

Comment: When you say that you import a fresh osm.bz2 file, are you saying that you downloaded it directly from the XAPI? From cloudmade? Have you tried to unzip the osm.bz2 file (or part of it) and look if the house number is correct on that street?

Comment: I use Extract file from planet.osm. Info about building I see in such format: <tag k="addr:housenumber" v="60"/>. And another one problem: at the end of all addresses I see "United states of America" instead of "Russian Federation".

Comment: You're hitting the border problem when using extracts with geocoding.  You'll have to (atleast I did) modify  the code and get some polygon defined around the covered area.  I've had this with the benelux subset once.   I believe the shape files could also help you there.

Answer (score 3):

It says [here](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/FAQ#How_was_the_address_calculated.3F) that the adress is calculate using a combination of `admin boundaries, is_in tags and place features`. For building level features addresses are calculated using the address of the most suitable street.

Also it says [here](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/FAQ#Why_doesn.27t_Nominatim_process_addr%3a.2A_tags_on_buildings) that nominatim does not process `addr:*` tags on buildings.

The main OSM site also uses `geonames` database in searching, so it may have different results.